# PHP header not redirecting

Tags: php, csv, warnings, xampp

I've been trying to forward a url after checking two initial conditions. It's a simple bit of code. And what I am trying to achieve is check two initial conditions that will be loaded from a CSV file then if the conditions meet I want to forward the user to a different page.

This is my CSV file contents

```
katz,26.06.2011,http://www.google.com


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
$name_value=$_GET['query'];
$fh = fopen('db.csv', 'r');
$now = date("d.m.Y"); 
$data=fgetcsv($fh); 
$name=$data[0];
$date=$data[1];
$url=$data[2];
if($name_value == $name AND $date>=$now)
{
   header("Location: $url");
}
else
  {
   echo("not successful<br>");
  }
echo "name1 is $name_value<br>";
    echo "name2 is $name<br>";
    echo "date is $date<br>";
    echo "now is $now<br>";
    exit;
?>
```

I am getting this warning

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/x/client_authorized.php:5) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/x/client_authorized.php on line 17

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: make sure no output is displayed before calling header(). Somewhere in client_authorized.php in line 5, the output has been started.

Comment: @Rakesh I've not called any other output before the header..and the echo statements before exit(); are only for testing purposes

Comment: even a whitespace, new lines could affect this.

Comment: The line `output started at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/x/client_authorized.php:5` will tell you exactly where the output happened. CHeck that line in your file for any white-space or other characters.

Comment: Try to view the generated page's source and see if you can detect a whitespace or a newline before the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send headers after the output is already started (the headers have to be the first things out the door).

Make sure you don't have anything (including whitespace -- like new lines, tabs, and space) before your opening `<?php`.

Answer (score 2):

You should also call exit() or die() after the header function call.

see redirect examples here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I agree. You should call `exit();` or `die()` after.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with output buffering on

```
$ <?php
$ ob_start();
$ --------
$ --------
$ ob_end_flush();
$ ?>
```